# Is there a way to convert string to a date with this format (2-Feb-19) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a `string` into a `date` before I can do some arithmetic on the date.

My string has this format `2-FEB-19`, I want to keep the same format after converting it to a `date`. How can I do that?

I tried `df['dates'].to_datetime('2-Feb-19', format='%d-%m-%y')` and I got an error message `"time data '2-Feb-19' does not match format '%d-%m-%y' (match)"`

Comment: Can you please format your code?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%m`, which wants a month as a zero-padded number, such as `02`.  use `%b`.

---

It looks from your question like you are dealing with a single string rather than a Pandas Series or other sequence.  For that, you can use `strptime()` from Python's `datetime` module in the standard library:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2-FEB-19', '%d-%b-%y')
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 2, 0, 0)
```

If you do really want to use Pandas, whether it be on a scalar (string) or sequence, you may want to use the `%b` format specifier:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2-FEB-19', format='%d-%b-%y')
Timestamp('2019-02-02 00:00:00')
```

Python's reference on `strptime` directives is at the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) docs.

---

Granted, Pandas (and the underlying date-parsing libraries it uses) are pretty good at inference, and will usually guess things right:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2-FEB-19')
Timestamp('2019-02-02 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the appropriate format:

`df['dates'].to_datetime('2-Feb-19', format='%d-%b-%y')`

%b "Month as locale’s abbreviated name":   Jan, Feb, …, Dec (en_US);

Ref. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html